# Combining MySQL tables through PHP

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables in my Database:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  rol varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


CREATE TABLE users_subjects (
  users_subjects_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id_fk int(11),
  subject_id_fk int(11),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(subject_id_fk) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (users_subjects_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


   CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `exercise_id_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `difficulty_change` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `difficulty_student` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `choice_answer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correct_answer` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `exercise_id_fk` (`exercise_id_fk`),
  KEY `answers_constraint` (`student_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `answers_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `answers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`exercise_id_fk`) REFERENCES `exercises` (`exercise_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Where in the table '`users`' there can be 2 types of users with different roles: '**teacher**' and '**student**'.

In addition, in the table '`users_subjects`', the subjects are related to the users.

In my code, when a user whose role is '**teacher**' and has X subjects enters with its login, a table appears and shows the '`answers`' table with the corresponding students who have the same subject as the teacher who entered. Like this:

```
$query = "select exercise_id_fk, student_id, difficulty_change, difficulty_student, correct_answer from answers
where student_id in (SELECT usAlu.user_id_fk FROM users uProf 
JOIN users_subjects usProf ON (usProf.user_id_fk = uProf.id) 
JOIN users_subjects usAlu ON (usProf.subject_id_fk = usAlu.subject_id_fk) 
JOIN users uAlu ON (usAlu.user_id_fk = uAlu.id) 
WHERE uProf.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' 
AND uAlu.rol = 'student');";
```

The problem is that in the '*student_id*' column, it shows the '*id*' of the student, instead of the username. I would like the username of the student to appear in the column '*student_id*' as in this example:

```
$query = "SELECT a.exercise_id_fk, u.username, a.difficulty_change, a.difficulty_student, a.correct_answer from answers
AS a JOIN users AS u ON a.student_id=u.id";
```

Can someone help me solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add  a join  for user

```
$query = "select a.exercise_id_fk
   , a.student_id
   , u.username
   , a.difficulty_change
   , a.difficulty_student
   , a.correct_answer 
from answers a
INNER JOIN users u ON a.student_id=u.id
where student_id in (
        ........
```

anyway you should avoid the use of PHP var in SQL .. you are at risk for sqlijection .. for avoid this you should take a look at your db driver for prepared statements and binding param

Comment: thank you for your answer @Scais but I tried it and it's not working correctly :/

Comment: update .. your question add  a proper (clear)  data sample, and your expected  result  .. anyway answer  updated .. removing a sintax errorr for a.a.

Comment: Okay I just eddited it like this:     `$query = "select a.exercise_id_fk
   , a.student_id
   , u.username
   , a.difficulty_change
   , a.difficulty_student
   , a.correct_answer
from answers
INNER JOIN users u ON a.student_id=u.id
where student_id in (SELECT usAlu.user_id_fk FROM users uProf 
JOIN users_subjects usProf ON (usProf.user_id_fk = uProf.id) 
JOIN users_subjects usAlu ON (usProf.subject_id_fk = usAlu.subject_id_fk) 
JOIN users uAlu ON (usAlu.user_id_fk = uAlu.id) 
WHERE uProf.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' 
AND uAlu.rol = 'student');";` But still not working:/

Comment: what do you meand  .. with "But still not working:"  ?   .. you have an error?   show the exact error message .. wrong result  .?   the add  a clear  data sample  ypur actula result  ..  and your expected result  ..

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.exercise_id_fk' in 'field list'`

Comment: added  proper a table name alias   answer a

Comment: yes I have a column with that name, I just didn't write it because the table was too long, but I updated my answer. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

SELECT a.exercise_id_fk,u.username,a.difficulty_change,a.difficulty_student,a.correct_answer from answers a,users u where a.student_id=u.id;

Comment: Some explanation would help as to why this would solve OP's problem.  Not sure how it gets up votes with nothing to explain it!